# How can I react with an emote from a command (Discord JDA)?

Tags: java, discord, bots

I've been trying to add a reaction roles command to my discord bot. But strangely it isn't working properly.
But the problem is that it worked six months ago. I haven't changed anything in my code.

The code stops here: `Emote emote = emotes.get(0);`

My class:

```
    package de.nameddaniel.bot.commands;

import java.util.List;

import de.nameddaniel.bot.main.LiteSQL;
import de.nameddaniel.bot.main.Utils;
import de.nameddaniel.bot.types.ServerCommand;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.Permission;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Emote;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Role;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;

public class ReactionRolesCommand implements ServerCommand {

    @Override
    public void performCommand(Member m, TextChannel channel, Message msg) {
        //!rr channel messageid :ok: ...
        
        String[] args = msg.getContentDisplay().split(" ");
        if(m.hasPermission(Permission.MANAGE_ROLES)) {
            if(args.length >= 5) {
                
                List<TextChannel> channels = msg.getMentionedChannels();
                List<Role> roles = msg.getMentionedRoles();
                List<Emote> emotes = msg.getEmotes();
                                
                System.out.println("3");
                
                    TextChannel tc = msg.getMentionedChannels().get(0);
                    String messageIDString = args[1];
                    Role role = roles.get(0);
                    
                    System.out.println("1");
                    
                    try {                       
                        long messageID = Long.parseLong(messageIDString);
                                                
                        Emote emote = emotes.get(0);
                        
                        tc.addReactionById(messageID, emote).queue();
                                                    
                        System.out.println("2");
                        
                        LiteSQL.onUpdate("INSERT INTO reactroles(guildid, channelid, messageid, emote, roleid) "
                                        + "VALUES(" + channel.getGuild().getIdLong() + ", " + tc.getIdLong() + ", "
                                        + messageID + ", '" + emote.getId() + "', " + role.getIdLong() + ")");

                        Utils.Embed("Deiner Nachricht in " + msg.getMentionedChannels() + " wurde die Reaktion " + msg.getEmotes()
                                    + " hinzugefügt.", channel, "Erfolgreich!");
                        
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("ReactionCommand");
                    }           
                
            }
            else
                Utils.Embed("Bitte benutze: !rr [MessageID] #channel [Emote] @Rolle", channel, "Falscher Syntax");
            System.out.println(args.length);
            
        }
        else
            msg.delete().queue();
    }

}
```

The error Code:

```
3
1
[JDA [0 / 1] MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Unknown Source)
    at de.nameddaniel.bot.commands.ReactionRolesCommand.performCommand(ReactionRolesCommand.java:40)
    at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.CommandManager.perform(CommandManager.java:43)
    at de.nameddaniel.bot.listener.CommandListener.onMessageReceived(CommandListener.java:25)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:430)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:82)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:69)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:147)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:122)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:948)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:835)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:813)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:986)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

What I could figure out is, that my List emotes is empty. But I have no idea why..

Most of the code is in German. So ask me if you need a translation.
If there is anything missing also please tell me.

Hope you can help me, Daniel :D

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was, that I confounded Emote with Emoji. So it has to be an Emoji instead of an emote.